# How do I write EF.Functions extension method?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I see that EF Core 2 has EF.Functions property [EF Core 2.0 Announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/12/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-1/) `which can be used by EF Core or providers to define methods that map to database functions or operators so that those can be invoked in LINQ queries`. It included LIKE method that gets sent to the database.

But I need a different method, SOUNDEX() that is *not* included. How do I write such a method that passes the function to the database the way `DbFunction` attribute did in EF6? Or I need to wait for MS to implement it? Essentially, I need to generate something like

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE SOUNDEX(lastname) = SOUNDEX(@param)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding new scalar method to `EF.Functions` is easy - you simply define extension method on `DbFunctions` class. However providing SQL translation is hard and requires digging into EFC internals.

However EFC 2.0 also introduces a much simpler approach, explained in [Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping) section of the *New features in EF Core 2.0* documentation topic.

According to that, the easiest would be to add a static method to your `DbContext` derived class and mark it with `DbFunction` attribute. E.g.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    [DbFunction("SOUNDEX")]
    public static string Soundex(string s) => throw new Exception();
}
```

and use something like this:

```
string param = ...;
MyDbContext db = ...;
var query = db.Customers
    .Where(e => MyDbContext.Soundex(e.LastName) == MyDbContext.Soundex(param));
```

You can declare such static methods in a different class, but then you need to manually register them using `HasDbFunction` fluent API.

Comment: I do't know how I missed it :)

Comment: @ivan-stoev. is there some guide or example on the extending? Say I want function to produce other expression then DB function call - `a @@ b` in psql for full text search. I checked how providers do it, and looks like `IMethodCallTranslator` and `RelationalCompositeMethodCallTranslator` are places to look at. But how can I insert a new CallTranslator to existing chain?

Comment: Hi @Igor, AFAIK currently there is no such guide/example. Providing such hooks is in EFC backlog plan, but I have no idea how you can do that currently (if possible at all).

Comment: You can use the `DbFunction.Translation` callback method.  You register this with the fluent api call `HasTranslation`.  Your callback method can then return any Expression it wants to inject into the output tree.  It will require some trial and error to see what you can get each db provider to output.

Comment: I found using EFC 2.2 that I needed to provide a blank schema to get this to work i.e. `[DbFunction("SOUNDEX", "")]` otherwise it was looking for the function in the `dbo` schema.

Answer (score 4):

EFC 3.0 has changed this process a little, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#udf-empty-string

Example of adding CHARINDEX in a partial context class:

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    [DbFunction("CHARINDEX")]
    public static int? CharIndex(string toSearch, string target) => throw new Exception();

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasDbFunction(typeof(MyDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(CharIndex)))
            .HasTranslation(
                args =>
                    SqlFunctionExpression.Create("CHARINDEX", args, typeof(int?), null));
    }
}
```