# Linq where condition on datetime.ToString()

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have following Linq code

```
// query = IQueryable<DataClass>
query = query.Where(m => m.Column1.Contains(model.search.value)
        || m.DateTimeColumn2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").StartsWith(model.search.value));

return query.ToList() // here the error is thrown
```

I get **NullReferenceException** error

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.NullReferenceException An exception
>   of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code:
>   'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()

if i commented out the line for 2nd column it works

```
//|| m.DateTimeColumn2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").StartsWith(model.search.value)
```

`model.search.value` is string value I am trying to filter all columns. The DateTimeColumn2 is in DateTime datatype in the database, but user input string, therefore Iam converting DateTimeColumn2 to string and try to filter to users value. Any idea, what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you verified that nothing in `model.search.value` is `null`?

Comment: `DateTimeColumn2` is mandatory and is of datetype `DateTime`, so each row has value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that the part...

```
|| m.DateTimeColumn2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").StartsWith(model.search.value)
```

...can't be translated into SQL (`ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")` isn't supported`), so EF-core auto-switches to client-side evaluation.

However, now the whole `Where` clause is evaluated client-side, including the first part,

```
m.Column1.Contains(model.search.value)
```

Now this first part has become susceptible to null reference exceptions. There are entities that have a `null` for `Column1`.

When you remove the `DateTimeColumn2` predicate the whole statement can be translated into SQL and evaluated by the database.

Comment: that makes sense ! thank you. Is there way how to workaround this unsupported `.ToString()` method ?

Comment: EF-core has this feature [`DbFunction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46214081/861716). I haven't tried it yet, but you may be able to map a function to a SQL datetime formatting function.

Comment: I tried `DbFunction` but the error is the same. I will workaround this issue with view object with additional DateTimeString column.

Comment: @Muflix If the target db is SqlServer. adding `[DbFunction("FORMAT", "")]public static string Format(DateTime value, string format) => value.ToString(format);` to the context class and replacing the `m.DateTimeColumn2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")` with `YourDbContext.Format(m.DateTimeColumn2, "dd.MM.yyyy")` should fix the issue (as Gert suggested)

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you i will try it, unfortunately i am using `sql server 2008 r2` which does not support `format` function. I tried it with my own scalar function which was using `convert` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your DateTimeColumn2 can have NULL values which is very normal for DateTime columns. Also you shouldn't convert it to a string but the search value to a datetime. Is the user searching like "01" to mean any 1st date of any month and\year?

```
query = query.Where(m => m.Column1.Contains(model.search.value)
        || !m.DateTimeColumn2.HasValue
        || m.DateTimeColumn2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").StartsWith(model.search.value));

return query.ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the exception is thrown because of any of the DateTimeColumn2 values might be null, check for non-nullness:

```
query = query.Where(m => ...
    || (m.DateTimeColumn2 != null &&
        m.DateTimeColumn2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").StartsWith(model.search.value)));
```

Comment: The `DateTimeColumn2` is `DateTime`, it is not `nullable`. To be sure I tried your code, but the error is the same :/ it is very strange.

Comment: Could it be that model  or search or value are null?