# What is the equivalient of SqlFunctions.Replicate in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am rewriting an existing ASP.NET MVC code into ASP.NET Core. I have the following query :

```
if (query.Any(usr => SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", EmployeeNumberPatternLength - usr.PersonNumber.Length) + usr.PersonNumber ==
                    SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", EmployeeNumberPatternLength - encryptedEmployeeNumber.Length) + encryptedEmployeeNumber)
{
    // other logic
}
```

I tried to use `EF.Functions` but there is not equivalent Replicate function.

Can anyone help me - how to do this in EF Core?

Additional info: the project is using .NetStandard 2.0

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write EF.Functions extension method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212704/how-do-i-write-ef-functions-extension-method)

Comment: As mentioned, i am  using this query in the class library project which is targetting .NetStandard2.0. So i am not able to use SqlFunctions.Replicate....

Comment: It is not telling you to use SqlFunctions.Replicate. It is showing you how to add a mapping to a database function not already pre-mapped.

Comment: Yes, but even when i try to create the [DbFunction] in the context, i had to write this SqlFunctions.Replicate right? or is there a better way? I tried like:

        [DbFunction]
        public static string Soundex(string s, int patternLength)
        {
            return SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", EmployeNumberPatternLength - usr.PersonNumber.Length) + usr.PersonNumber
        }

Comment: It shows you [right there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46214081/11683). `[DbFunction("REPLICATE")] public static string Replicate(string s, int patternLength) => throw new Exception();`. And then in the query `query.Any(usr => MyDbContext.Replicate("0", EmployeeNumberPatternLength - usr.PersonNumber.Length) + usr.PersonNumber == MyDbContext.Replicate("0", EmployeeNumberPatternLength - encryptedEmployeeNumber.Length) + encryptedEmployeeNumber)`. Why would you even try to put a specific call to `Replicate`, with the `"0"` and the subtraction, inside a generic mapping?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was wrongly invoking the Replicate which is not required.